# How to combine parameter and static value in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have Copy Data Activity in Azure Data Factory.
I have OnPrem File system as Sink dataset.

Folder value is currently "Dev/Customers/Nissan".

I would like to use @pipeline().parameters.Environment for "Dev" value.

However following did not work
"@pipeline().parameters.OnPremLoad_OnPremEnv/Customers/Nissan"

Please advice how to concatenate parameter and dynamic value.

Answer (score 1):

Use [concat()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#concat) function to add parameter to static value in the expression.

Ex:

Expression: `@concat(pipeline().parameters.Environment,'/Customers/Nissan')`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey @Kenny_I, I did reproduce this issue and the solution worked for me; do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot?